# How to know which class called another class?

Tags: ios

I've got classes A, B & C in an iPhone project. While the iPhone app is running, either class (A or B) can instantiate an object of class C. How can I know in class C, which class instantiated the object (A or B)? Is there any way of knowing without adding an ivar to C? I tried using superclass but I'm either using it wrong or it's not meant for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superclass is what the object inherits from, not the creator of an object.

One way to communicate back is through a delegate - can you get (A or B) to set the delegate property on C? That is kind of like the ivar you want to avoid, but using a protocol it is considered fine OO code.

It would be good to know why C needs to know. Does he need to send a method? Delegation is great for that. If not, then using custom init methods as mentioned by William Bonar is a possibility. If you are working with ViewController then you have methods such as presentingViewController, etc.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: Thanks, it is just a view being presented over another view so there is no ViewController involved, that would have been the best approach but the delegate option is working perfectly! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from you comment that the class c is not under your control.

You can subclass c and add a new init methods `initFromClass: (id) parent` in the init you can set whatever flags you wish

Comment: Sorry for not stating about the control. Actually I do have control over class C. Class C is a help View which can be showed from other two different views (A & B) so I need to know which one is showing class C so I can know which texts are shown to the user without having to create another help class.